# how do i check values individually of appended inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do i check values individually of appended inputs

example i want to get the value of only the second appended input thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".addinput").click(function(){
        $('.samplediv').append('<input type="text" class="sampleinput">');
    }); 
</script>

<div class="samplediv">
    <input type="text" class="sampleinput">
</div>
<button class="addinput"></button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique class for each input and use that class to get the value. For the second one, use something like:

```
$("input.num-2).val();
```

```js
var num = 1;
$(".addinput").click(function(){
  $('.samplediv').append('<input type="text" class="sampleinput num-' + num + '">');
  num++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="samplediv">
</div>
<button class="addinput">Add input</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is just one way (not the best way) to accomplish what you are asking for.**

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/zzukok0j/

```
$(".addinput").click(function(){

  $('.samplediv').append('<input type="text" class="sampleinput">');

    var counter = 0;
    $('.sampleinput').each(function(poop) {
      if(counter===1) {
        alert( $(this).val() );
      } else {
          counter++;
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Sir I am trying to achieve to check value of every input with that same class name if it is empty. A button would be enabled once all those inputs are filled up and if you append an input again it would be disabled because it is empty hope you understand my question thanks

Comment: Then you need to change the code inside of the `.each()` method to something like: `if ($(this).val() === ""){ $('button').attr('disabled','true'); break; }

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code will allow you to get the value of each of the appended inputs.

```
var $inputs = $('.samplediv input');
$inputs.each(function(index) {
    value = this.val();
    // now you can use value for whatever you need
    console.log(value);
});
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

use jquery each function to select each field and do whatever you want...

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    //do something
});
```